# Azure WebJob DWASFiles access denied

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have 2 Azure websites running (Live and Staging), each with a continuous WebJob that processes documents uploaded to the site.
Nothing has been added/changed on the live site for a few weeks. So this issue has come out of the blue entirely.

In the WebJob we read files from App_Data for the website, analyse and store them to a database. No additional file writes take place. Some time in the last week the WebJobs started failing with:

> Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites' is denied.

I can't see anyone else who's got a similar issue that's occurred recently. So I'm a little stumped!

**My Solution**
As I couldn't find any resources describing what to do or what had changed in Azure. I went along a different route and extracted the WebJob logic into a Hangfire task. (hangfire.io - a fantastic task runner)

Not sure if that will help anyone else. But it solved my issues.

Comment: Since you actually don't have access to `C:\DWASFiles\Sites` maybe something in your webjob  changed..

Comment: There's been nothing change on the live site's web job which is the very peculiar bit!

Answer (score 1):

Try using D:\home\site\wwwroot\ to point to your wwwroot directory.
Azure Websites remaps the root directory to be used with D:\Home

Comment: What is the correct way of doing `Path.GetDirectoryName((new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath);` to find the locally running directory of the WebJob? Or is the only option likely to be to hardcode the path?

Comment: @BenFord you can use the %HOME% environment variable. That'll get you to the home folder, and then you can naviagate to site\wwwroot relative to it.